# How to Underline (with Linebreaking) within Contiguously Highlighted Text Using Soul

Tags: macros, color, highlighting, soul, underline

I would like to use the command `\ul` within a block of text that is contiguously highlighted using the macro contained in the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{soulred}{red!30}
\sethlcolor{soulred}

\makeatletter
\def\SOUL@hlpreamble{%
\setul{\dimexpr\dp\strutbox+2pt}{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox+2pt\relax}
\let\SOUL@stcolor\SOUL@hlcolor
\SOUL@stpreamble
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\lineskip}{0pt}

\hl{I would like to underline within this highlighted sentence. Here is another sentences to illustrate that the highlighting is also contiguous.}\\[15pt]
\hl{I would like to \ul{underline} within this highlighted sentence. Here is another sentences to illustrate that the highlighting is also contiguous.}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

As you can see from the output, using the command `\ul` within `\hl` produces an error. If I replace `\ul` by `\underline`, I still get an an error---the black box disappears as well as the word that I am underlining.

How may I underline with linebreaking capability (that is why I am trying to use `\ul`) and within the purview of the `\hl` command?

Comment: see § 22 Nested soul commands: in the soul documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

soul can't nest such commands, at least not if you want to allow linebreaks also in the inner command. With lualatex and the lua-ul package it would work:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{luacolor,xcolor}
\usepackage[soul]{lua-ul}
\colorlet{soulred}{red!30}
\LuaULSetHighLightColor{soulred}
\begin{document}

\hl{I would like to underline within this highlighted sentence. Here is another sentences to illustrate that the highlighting is also contiguous.}\\[15pt]
\hl{I would like to \ul[top=-0.2ex,height=1pt]{underline within this highlighted sentence. Here is another sentences to} illustrate that the highlighting is also contiguous.}
\end{document}
```

[image]